# Is a global list variable okay in my app, or should I use an alternative?

Tags: ruby, list, variables, global-variables

I am working on building a hangman type game.  I have been reading a lot about global variables being bad, and I am wanting to use the best practices that I can.  That being said, I am currently declaring a several variables of different categories, and each category variable contains a list of words for the program to choose from.

Is it okay to declare these as global, or should I place them in a method or something else like that?

They will never be changed or anything like that, they are just to be accessed so the program can pick a random word for the player to guess.  Is this considered okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global *variables* are generally bad. Global *constants* (which you seem to have) are a bit better.

Just use the proper syntax:

```
$words = %w(foo bar) # bad, global var syntax
WORDS = %w(foo bar) # good, syntax for constants
```

Although I would scope that constant to some module or class, to not pollute the global namespace. You don't need it to be really global, right? Something like this:

```
class Game
  WORDS = %(foo bar)
end

# then
Game::WORDS
```

Better yet, hide this constant in a method:

```
class Game
  def self.words
    %(foo bar)
  end
end

# then 
Game.words
```

This way, if later you need to read the list of words from, say, file, you just change implementation of the method and the rest of the code doesn't need to be touched.

Comment: Okay cool.  That makes a lot of sense.  I didn't even think about having it read a list of words from a file, that would probably make things a lot easier in the future.  Thanks for reply, that helped a lot.

Comment: @bshock84: btw, you should accept the most helpful answer to your question (in this case, mine :) ). To do that, tick a checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I'm new posting here, been reading for a while.  I have a feeling I"ll be around a lot though.

Comment: @bshock84: I started posting after two years of lurking :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sergio and in addition I use a technique to store that kind of variables in a configuration file, easy when you want to test values or distribute and separate from your code. I herefor use the yaml gem.
In addition I use Structs to hold the constants or variables, they are designed for this kind of data.

Here an example of such a file

```
--- !ruby/struct
  DEBUG_LEVEL: DEBUG #example of a constant
  database: !ruby/struct
    development: !ruby/struct
      tablename: tablename
      sequence: seq_osgn_rowversion
      connection:
        adapter: oracle_enhanced
        database: (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = ORATCP.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = hostname)(Port = 1526)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = SIDID)))
        username: user
        password: pass
```

You load them like this:

```
require 'yaml'
CONFIG = YAML::load_file("./config.yaml")
```

and the values are accessed like this

```
connection = CONFIG.database.development
```